# Using two struts2 taglibs in each other

Tags: java, struts2, taglib

I want to use two struts taglib in each other, something like this:

```
< s:property value="url-< s:property value="number"/>"/>
```

or

```
< s:property value="url-${number}"/>
```

but I got the following error in the second one:

According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute values does not accept any expressions.

Anybody has a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: You misstyped "properties" instead of "property", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was too easy!

As our friend leonbloy said, number is now in value stack when it generated in an iterator.
so I should just write it's name:

```
<s:property value="url-number"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
<s:property value="'url-'+'%{number}'"/>
```

Struts accepts OGNL expressions in the format %{yourAttribute}

Answer (score 0):

If the "`number`" value is fixed (at the moment of the jsp generation; i.e., it is not set in the jsp, or changed in an iterator), you'd better refactor it to a method in your action. For example, if the "`number`" is a property in your action:

```
  public String getUrlWithNumber() {
     return "url-" + String.valueOf(getNumber());
  }  

  <s:property value="urlWithNumber"/>
```

elsewhere you could try something as (untested)

```
  public String buildUrlWithNumber(int number) {
     return "url-" + String.valueOf(number);
  }  


  <s:property value="buildUrlWithNumber(${number})"/>
```

or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately the number is generated in an iterator.
and when I use something like your second solution (as I wrote in my question), I got this error:
"According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute values does not accept any expressions."

Comment: Ah, OGNL is a pain... You have the "number" available in the value stack, so that `<s:property value="number"/>` outputs it ? Then, you might try with `<s:property value="buildUrlWithNumber(%{number})"/>` (or #number , I never remember)